# Вызов сниппета в tpl

Tags: modx, revo

Добрый день! Есть необходимость запускать сниппет в чанке, эта чанка предназначена для списка WayFinder

Т.е. сначала вы запускаем WayFinder у которого есть параметром чанка которая формирует вывод записи. Внутри этой чанки есть вызов другого сниппета.

Вызов WayFinder:

```
[[!Wayfinder? 
   &startId=`[[*id]]`
   &outerTpl=`wf.tdOuter`
   &rowTpl=`wf.tdRow`
   &level=`1`
   &hereClass=`act` 
   &firstClass=`` 
   &lastClass =``
]]
```

Содержимое wf.tdRow:

```
<tr>
    <td class="justify">[[+wf.description]]</td>
    <td>
        [[!Peoples?
            &where=`User.id:IN ([[+members]])`
        ]]
    </td>
    [[+wf.wrapper]]
</tr>
```

Таким образом в Peoples не передается [[+members]] , похоже воспринимает как текст. Вместо значений.

как сделать что бы заработало?

Comment: попробуйте передать members из wayfinder: ``&members=`[[+members]]` ``

Comment: Что за "members"? Откуда ты его берешь и берешь ли ты его с правильным префиксом?